# How to prevent an object to sort keys by alphabetical order?

Tags: javascript

I have an object whose values I want to sort by descending order. Exemple:

```js
//This
{
  c: 34,
  a: 30,
  b: 21
 }
 
 // Instead of
{
  a: 30,
  b: 21,
  c: 34
 }
```

I can sort it this way:

```js
function sortObject (obj){
  return Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => (a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1))
  }
```

Then, I need to transform this sorted array back into an object. No matter the method, the object goes back to auto-sorting its key by alphabetical order. How to keep my new order?

Here is the method I've used:

```js
sortedObject.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: value }), {});
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you taken a json from it? maybe your user agent does the sorting for `console.log`.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with my useragent, I have the same issue in node.

Comment: your code is working fine, if you combine all parts to a working snippet.

Comment: You should change the sort compareFunction to `(a, b) => b[1] - a[1]`. If the values are same, then 0 should be returned from the function for consistent sorting

Comment: You are not returning anything from`sortObject` function and you are calling `sortObject` function. Change it to: `function sortObject (obj) { return Object.entries(....` and `var newObject = sortedObject(yourObjHere).reduce(.....)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.fromEntries` to put back into an object.

example ->

```js
var o =
{
  c: 34,
  a: 30,
  b: 21
};

function sortObject (obj){
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => (a[1] - b[1])));
}

console.log(sortObject(o));
```

Comment: You can change the sort compareFunction to `(a, b) => b[1] - a[1]`. If the values are same, then 0 should be returned from the function for consistent sorting

Comment: @adiga  Yes, good point. I just copied OP's code here.  I'll update..

Comment: Object.fromEntries doesn't work.

Comment: @DoneDeal0  If you run the above snippet, it seems to work.. What browser / version are running.

Comment: I've just tried it in a codepen. It goes back to a natural a,b,c ordering. Also, typescript refuses to use this method in my real project.

Comment: @DoneDeal0  It should not make any difference, have you a link to the codepen?   Does the above snippet work for you.?

Comment: Yes, the snippet works fine in SO, not here: https://codepen.io/MonsieurLeland/pen/dyGGmBZ?editors=0011

Comment: @DoneDeal0 check your browser's console. Codepen's console seems to be giving wrong order

Comment: It works there too, it's just a bug in the way CodePen is displaying Objects.  Look in the browsers console and you will see the correct output.   I believe CodePen maybe designed its Object viewer before Object's had a defined order, recent ES Spec has giving objects a defined order based on insertion, old ES5 spec's never stipulated, so CodePen is just showing in key order instead.